# Itipiso Chanting

Tags: personal-practice, chant

I try to do abit of chanting everyday, and I have tingling feelings in my upper body (spine/arms) the moment I begin chanting starting with Namo Tassa, Itipiso, homage to Dhamma, homage to Sangha, when I chant other suttas like bojjhana sutta I get the tingling feeling too. However when I do reading of the suttas, I do not get the tingling feeling. I'd like to ask if it happens to everyone who does chanting, and what is the cause for this tingling feeling.

Comment: It sounds like hyperventilation. http://www.emedicinehealth.com/hyperventilation/page3_em.htm

Comment: It's not hyperventilation. It's piti (exciting) and sukkha (happiness).

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. There are a lot of sensations (one of the 5 aggregates) which arise and pass in our body which we are not sensitive to.

When we are thinking, listening, tasting, seeing, doing different things, we experience different sensations. No exception when you are chanting or reading. Only thing is that you are not sensitive enough to see the sensations when you read. When you chant the chanting itself causes larger vibrations which you can easily sense. Especially Pirith and Mantras which generally create much vibrations than normal chattering.

Answer (score 1):

The tingling sensations may be the arising of Rapture (Pali : Piti).  This is a positive mental factor. When it arise, simply know it as it is, that it is impermanent and not self.

Comment: Hi pilgrim and Welcome to Buddhism.SE. We've put together some useful information to help you get started [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?). :)

Comment: Hello Pilgrim. I would also like to say welcome to Buddhism SE. Regarding your answer, could you provide a bit more text/description and preferebly some references to the texts? Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar feelings. It helped not to attach that (Buddhist teaching, heh?;) Just focus to chanting and continue. Maybe problem arise due wrong breathing or unfasting of some inner tension...

Answer (score 0):

When you are chanting you are breathing differently then when you are not. When you are chanting your body is vibrating differently then when you are not. It makes reasonable sense that the differences in breathing and vibrating could cause "tingling feelings" in your body that would not be there when breathing normally. This is a very normal event.

Answer (score 0):

They are piti (exciting) and sukkha (happiness). They are the opposite of stress.

They are very important for the concentration meditation. You should remember that feeling and meditate them on daily life, such as reading Sutta with that feeling, or do the Anapanassati meditation with that feeling, or watching politic news with that feeling.